# iOS safari input caret color

Tags: ios, css, safari

I have a small CSS issue with Safari on iPhone device. My search input is blue and when user focuses on it, caret is almost invisible:

[image: Caret]

In all desktop browsers, it has right color (white), even on desktop Safari. Any idea how to fix this and change caret color on iOS device?

Input styles:

```
input {
  background-color: $stateBlue;
  height: $navbarItemHeight;
  padding: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: $white;
  border-radius: $borderRadius;
  font-size: 1.1666666667em; // 16px
  -moz-appearance:none;
  -webkit-appearance:none;

  &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Not really, seems that it's not possible via CSS in native iOS device.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up implementing my own caret.

Comment: @GentiSaliu how? did you do that with an image?

Comment: I used a `div` and positioned it to overlap with the standard caret, applied styling, added blinking behavior using timeouts and keyinput listeners to update its position whenever a user entered something in the text field.

Comment: @GentiSaliu could you provide a code sample of your implementation? especially the javascript part would be interesting. how do you place the div over the caret position? we were facing the same problem last year and thought there was no solution to this. thx

Answer (score 9):

There is a [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#caret-color) for this called [`caret-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) which can be used like this:

```css
input[type="text"].custom {
  caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>default caret:</label>
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label>custom red caret:</label>
  <input type="text" class="custom"/>
</div>
```

It's [currently supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color) by Chrome (also on Android), Firefox, Opera and Safari (including iOS).